GLIBC Compile Error: Implicit Declaration of Function
I am trying to compile GLIBC from source however during that process I get the following error:
../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_gammaf_r.c: In function ‘__ieee754_gammaf_r’:
../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_gammaf_r.c:127:32: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__builtin_roundeven’; did you mean ‘__builtin_round’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   double m = z - 0x1.7p+1, i = __builtin_roundeven(m), step = __builtin_copysign(1.0,i);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                __builtin_round
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

I have tried compiling using the following:
git clone https://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git glibc-devel
cd glibc-devel
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/home/a0504063/bin/python/glibc --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu CC="gcc -m64" CXX="g++ -m64" CFLAGS="-O2 -Wno-error" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -Wno-error"
make

This yields the above error. As is demonstrated in the configure command I am using -Wno-error to try and suppress the default "all warnings being treated as errors" behavior. However, this option is prepended to the default options list which causes it to be ignored.
I am currently using:

git commit hash: 18596c5415
gcc/g++ version: 8.5.0
OS: RedHat 8 (this is what the company servers currently run and I have no option to change)


someone fixed this bug 4 days ago ... https://patchwork.sourceware.org/project/glibc/patch/20241025182614.2022697-2-adhemerval.zanella@linaro.org/ not sure when it will hit mainstream as it is under review, you can try downgrading glibc in the mean time


gcc/g++ version: 8.5.0

Your GCC is too old.
From the patch comment:

__builtin_roundeven is not support on gcc older than version 10.

Your options are:

use older GLIBC sources
use newer GCC
apply above patch
wait for that patch to be committed, and then build newest GLIBC sources

P.S. GLIBC-2.32 release notes show that it was tested on x86_64 using GCC 8.2.1.
So using latest released GLIBC version should be fine with your version of GCC.
